# JQuery: Unable to get property from each img in a list of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a snippet of HTML, and iterate through each image within that snippet and apply a listener function and modify the image.  However, using JQuery's `.each()` function is not allowing me to use functions such as `.prop()` to get/set image attributes.  How can I apply functions such as `.prop()` to elements iterated over by the `.each()` function.

```
//formatImg simply returns a URL to the resource
var images = '<div class="flex-row">\
                <div class="img">\
                    <img class="img-cover" data-src="' + formatImg(gallery.posts[0].image, 'medium') + '">\
                </div>\
                <div class="img">\
                    <img class="img-cover" data-src="' + formatImg(gallery.posts[1].image, 'medium') + '">\
                </div>\
            </div>';

var location = gallery.posts[0].location.address || 'No Location';

var elem = $('<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 tile story">\
        <div class="tile-body">\
            <div class="frame"></div>\
            <div class="hover">\
                <p class="md-type-body1">' + (gallery.caption || '') + '</p>\
                <ul class="md-type-body2">\
                    <li>' +  gallery.posts.length +  (gallery.posts.length == 1 ? ' photo' : ' photos') +'</li>\
                </ul>\
            </div>\
            ' + images + '\
        </div>\
        <div class="tile-foot">\
            <div class="hover">\
                <a href="/gallery/'+ gallery._id +'" class="md-type-body2">See all</a>\
                <!--<span class="mdi mdi-library-plus icon pull-right"></span>-->\
                <!--<span class="mdi mdi-download icon toggle-edit toggler pull-right"></span>-->\
            </div>\
            <div>\
                <div class="ellipses">\
                    <span class="md-type-body2">' + location + '</span>\
                    <span class="md-type-caption">' + getTimeAgo(new Date().getTime(), gallery.time_created) +'</span>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    </div>'
);

elem.find('img.img-cover').each(function(){
    _this = $(this);
    console.log(_this.prop('data-src'));
    attachOnImageLoadError(_this);
    _this.prop('src',_this.prop('data-src'));
});
```

The `console.log(_this.prop('data-src'))` from within `each`, it returns `undefined` for every image.

Comment: `_this.prop('data-src')` -> `_this.data('src')`; What is the return value of `formatImg(...)`?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment.  I'll try that

Comment: and formatImg returns a URL for the image

Comment: Beautiful!  That worked, thank you!  If you make it an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with each().  Your problem is that you're trying to use prop() to handle HTML5 data attributes.

"data-src" is not an HTML property, therefore _this.prop('data-src') returns null.  You would run into the same problem if you were using prop() to try to write to a data-src attribute.

Instead, to read a data attribute named data-src using jquery, use data().  So use _this.data('src').

See https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5 for more help.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple script below that may help you to make it work:

```js
var images = '<div class="flex-row">\
                <div class="img">\
                   <img class="img-cover" data-src="img-1" />\
                </div>\
                <div class="img">\
                    <img class="img-cover" data-src="img-2">\
                </div>\
            </div>';

$(images).find('img.img-cover').each(function() {
  alert($(this).data('src'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Isn't that fixed when I put the entire string literal within `$()`, thus making elem a JQuery object?